# What is the difference between -r and -x when attaching to a screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

I found out today that both my friend and I use different ways of connecting to a screen. I've always used the form `-x` and he uses `-r`. I read the man pages but I wasn't able to come up with a test case that produced different results.

I opened two consoles on the same account and attached to it successfully with `-r` and `-x`.

What is the difference between these commands?

I could only find that the error message is different if I try to attach to the same screen I'm already attached to:

```
$ screen -r 1486
There is no screen to be resumed matching 1486.
```

and

```
$ screen -x 1486
Attaching from inside of screen?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Invoking-Screen

`-x` attaches to a session even if you are attached to it already.

`-r` attaches only to a session if it has no client currently attached to it.

If you want to test it (the test you did sounds rather like you tried to attach to the screen-session from inside the screen session, which you definitely should not do), you need two separate terminal sessions. In the first, do screen to start a screen session and attach to it. In the second, do `screen -r`:

```
screen -r
There is a screen on:
    562503.pts-2.E595   (Attached)
There is no screen to be resumed.
```

Now do `screen -x` and you will attach to the session. If you put both terminals side by side, you will also notice that what you do on one of the terminals will be visible also on the other terminal.

So in short: `-r` for attaching a detached session, `-x` to attach to an attached session without detaching the other session.